# How long does it usually take to get an offer letter after a confirmation for a postdoc?

Tags: postdocs

I was interviewed for a postdoc position in the USA and got a confirmation mail 2 months ago. It's been 2.5 months not getting an offer letter yet. How much more time would it take?

Comment: Why don't you email them and ask? Also, your question is unclear: did they say that your interview was successful and that they will be making an offer?

Comment: What did they say in the confirmation email?

Comment: They have confirmed a position in their lab in mail clearly 2.5 months back. I have emailed them last month about the hr process and updates but there is no response from that side. I want to know that how much more time it would take to get the offer letter?

Comment: Call them or email them and politely ask, stating that you need to evaluate and decide shortly on which one to accept.

Answer (score 3):

It takes what it takes and while 2.5 months seems long it may be because they think you are satisfied with the status quo and all else is but a formality. You can ask them, especially if you have any doubts about its eventual arrival.

But it might just be that the season implies that they are working with reduced staff and have what they consider more pressing concerns to get ready for the coming academic year.

It could also be that the formal process requires several signatures and some of those folks are away for a bit.

Ask and ye shall (probably) learn.

Comment: They have confirmed a position in their lab in mail clearly 2.5 months back. I have emailed them last month about the hr process and updates but there is no response from that side. I want to know that how much more time it would take to get the offer letter?

Comment: Only they can answer that, @qwerty.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for how it works in the USA, but in my experience the key parameter that governs when you get the formal offer letter and contract for a postdoc is amount of time remaining until your start date, not the amount of time since the informal offer. If the start date is still some way off, even if it has been months since you had a positive outcome, the person whose responsibility it is may well regard it as not being urgent.

Of course, you can reasonably ask them when you can expect to receive it.